# passing an argument to a bash script that is run by redirecting to bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to either pass an argument or set a variable for a bash script that gets executed remotely. Part of the trouble is that server I am ssh-ing into does a chroot after connection. The only way I have found to execute a script looks like this:

```
ssh user@server 'bash -ex' <  /tmp/script
```

I have a need for a variable in that script. It doesn't matter if it is an arg or a environment variable passed to bash somehow. The only way I can think of to solve this problem is by doing something like:

```
sed -e s/VAR/VAR=dog/g /tmp/script > /tmp/replaced
ssh user@server 'bash -ex' < /tmp/replaced
```

I think it's obvious why I don't like that solution. Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure `SendEnv` (client) and `AcceptEnv` (server) properly, you can have ssh send the variable for you.

```
VAR=dog ssh user@server 'bash -ex' < /tmp/replaced
```

Comment: I can't seem to get that working. I have stripped things down to a basic ssh server var=dog. It logs me, runs my bashrc file and kicks me back out. What I am missing? The only thing I can think of is OpenSSH 3.4 vs 5.1

Comment: Unfortunately one of my machines has on older version of ssh that doesn't support AccpectEnv. I am unable to upgrade ssh on that box. Thanks for your help anyways. I didn't know that SendEnv existed.